# iOS: switch to second ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a script that uses `Reachability` to check for an Internet connection. If there is No Internet I want it to load a second `ViewController`. This is what I have so far:

```
-(BOOL) hasInternet {
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if( internetStatus == NotReachable){
        SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{

    }
    return YES;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Attempt to present SecondViewController: 0x7ff780628d10 on ViewController: 0x7ff780719830 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: r u doing this on app delegate ?

Comment: No, this is in the first ViewController.

Comment: Make first view controller as root view and the present the second

Comment: Hi Mr.T, many thanks for your help. I am so new to Xcode I am totally lost when it come to making the the first view controller the root view controller, can you point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Look for how to make a uiview controller a root view programmatically, there are many examples out there

Answer (score 1):

> You are attempting to present another viewController while first ViewController has yet not loaded.

**Solution:**

1. Call your function inside viewDidAppear() method.
2. Write View Controllers Nib Name that you want to load